# apache virtual host subdomain not working correctly

Tags: linux, dns, apache-http-server, virtual-host

I am trying to configure a subdomain: api.example.com
(exapmle.com is replaced by my actual domain name)

I already had virtual hosts set up with 2 sites:
example.com and example.nl
they both had separate directories and where working correctly as separate sites.

Now I want to add api.example.com also with its own separate documentroot. I added a config file called: "api.example.com.conf" with this inside:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@api.example.com
ServerName api.example.com
ServerAlias www.api.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/api.example.com/html
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.api.example.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =api.example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

I added the folder /var/www/api.example.com/html with an example index.html inside. I gave the folder the right permissions. After that I enabled the site with: "a2ensite api.example.com.conf" and restarted apache.

I added a new record to the example.com records. It is an A record with api.example.com and it redirects to the same ip as example.com because they are on the same server.

After doing all of this I expected that when I went to api.example.com that it would show me the example index.html that I had created but it did not. When I go to api.example.com it is the same thing as if I would go to example.com.

How do I make it so that api.example.com has its own document root that works correctly?

Comment: Did you reload Apache after adding this configuration?

Comment: Yes, I did reload apache,

Comment: Have you tried omitting the Rewrite rules?

Comment: Yes, I have and I did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I am forcing all my domains to https but I did not yet have SSL setup for my new subdomain. I did have a virtual host for http://api.example.com, but my server does not allow HTTP so it redirected to https and because there was no virtual host for https://api.example.com it just redirected to the main domain.

Comment: Hi C1rcu1tB04rd, the answer section is intended for answers only please edit your question or use comments to provide supplements and delete this one.

Comment: But that’s not a question update, it’s a proper answer. “There was no vhost `api.example.com` on `*:443`”.